# Issues submitting form on Drupal with docker

Tags: docker, drupal

I have setup a Drupal website locally using Docker. The website loads correctly but I can't seem to pass the login form. I am redirected to the login screen without any error message.

My local URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000 and I tried to set the base url and cookie domain values in my settings files but this has no effect.

I noticed I was able to login if I am not using clean URLs (through index.php?q=user)

But once logged in to the admin area, I can't submit any form (creating new content, disabling module etc...), the page just reloads with no error message

I have no errors under the status report, nothing in the Apache logs, no error in the console.

My settings files looks like this:

```
    <?php
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'db',
  'username' => 'user',
  'password' => '123',
  'host' => php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? '127.0.0.1' : 'db',
  'prefix' => '',
  'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
);

    $update_free_access = FALSE;
    $drupal_hash_salt = '';
    ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
    ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 200000);
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2000000);
```

My DockerFile:

```
FROM php:7.1.2-apache 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y git\
    && apt-get install -y libicu-dev\
    && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && apt-get install -y zip \
    && apt-get install -y unzip \
    && apt-get install -y vim

ADD . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
        && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/ \
        && ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN composer global require hirak/prestissimo
```

And my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  database_data:
    driver: local

services:
  www:
    build: .
    ports: 
        - "8001:80"
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/
        - ./docker/apache/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    links:
        - db
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysqldump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      links: 
        - db:db
      ports:
        - 8000:80
      environment:
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
```

Comment: did you try to set `$base_url='http://127.0.0.1:8000'` or `$base_url='http://your_vhost_name:8000'` if you are on local environnement ?

Comment: @Fky yes I have but it made no difference

Comment: and 8001 , your conf talk about 8001 port for www

Comment: @Fky yeah I actually tested your suggestion with 8001 which is the right port. After more debugging, it seems my issue come from my vhost volume not working